# WPF chart control for medical software

Tags: .net, wpf

I am going to rewrite chart from some medical software to WPF. The chart is pretty complex and to save time I decided to use/buy 3rd party control. I understand to answer specifically you need more details but could you advise best WPF chart control from your personal experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Full disclosure: I own SciChart Ltd and was involved in the development of SciChart**

Admitedly I am biased, but I have developed a lightweight chart component for precisely this use. There are plenty of choices for WPF chart components, but few that offer truly high performance for scientific or financial use.

As a response to this need, I created a high performance [WPF chart](http://www.scichart.com/) component called SciChart. SciChart seeks to fill the gap for ultra high performance scientific / stock charts and as part of its optimisation it uses proprietary resampling algorithms to reduce the dataset before drawing, immediate mode rendering and a host of other optimisations such as object pooling and resource re-use.

Please click on following link to view a [performance comparison](http://www.scichart.com/wpf-chart-performance-comparison). The chart is able to draw multiple series totalling 5 or 6-figure point counts at interactive framerates (30FPS depending on hardware). This is equivalent to around 2million datapoints per second.

Best regards,

Comment: We've been using SciChart for the past 12 months and have been quite pleased.

Answer (score 1):

For me Microsoft chart (included in .Net 4.0) is really good and free.

(Microsoft buy Dundas chart, so it's a kind of evolution, the client side is really good but the webcontrol is really limited).